# Explain the difference in this while loop please

Tags: while-loop

Example:

```
x = 0
while x <= 10:
  x += 2
  print(x)
```

Results for this will be 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 , 10

If I switch the postion of print(x) and x += 2. The results will be 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12.

Please explain to me the thought process for this.

Thanks

Comment: What programming language is this? And I'm pretty sure you have those results backwards.

Comment: It's a matter of whether you print after you increase x, or before. And as John said, I think your results are backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is Python. Basically the code will get executed in the order it is written. I suggest you to take a sheet of paper and follow the lines of code, trying to figure out what happens and what is the value of your variable at each step. The output will be the values that your variable had when it got printed with the `print` function.